# How can I make the object path / url relate to object name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the object like

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :name, type: String
  field :notes, type: String
end
```

My url to one of my object when I show it was like `http://localhost:3000/coins/5a2e9e460d5fdd0a32153c31`

How can I make the url relate to the object name (#{book.name}) like

```
http://localhost:3000/coins/harrypotter
```

or

```
http://localhost:3000/coins/mazerunner
```

or

```
http://localhost:3000/coins/coolbook
```

Comment: [Overriding Named Route Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters) explains how you can change the `:id` part in your routes to another attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem and its very simple

Comment: Can I re routes the link . Like http://localhost:3000/coins/coolbook to http://localhost:3000/coolbook

Comment: You can do it in routes.rb: `match '/:id', to: 'coins#show'`. But i would not suggest removing the resource type "coins" from the path.

Comment: thank you bro . I just play to make a coin info page . so it's like coin.com/btc rather than coin.com/coins/btc